# Authorization failed error when trying to download from an anchor tag

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, authentication

When I try it in PostMan I can download the file by adding the token to the header. I can't find a way to add the token on the header. Is that something that should be in the frontend or in the backend?

React js

```
<a
  href={process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL +`/files/download/${props.id}`}
  rel="noreferrer"
  target="_blank"
  download
  className="download-link"
  >
   Download File
</a>
```

Express js:

```
router.get('/download/:fid', async (req, res, next) => {
  const fileId = req.params.fid;
  let filePost;
  try {
    filePost = await File.findById(fileId);
  } catch (err) {
    return next(new HttpError("Error", 500));
  }
  console.log(filePost.file);
  res.download(filePost.file);
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downloading a resource with pure HTML (an `<a>` anchor or a `<form>`) produces only requests with "standard" headers like `Accept-Language` or `Accept-Encoding`, *never* with a token header. So what you try is impossible with pure HTML.

What you could do it make a request with the Javascript function `fetch` and convert the response to a download URL with [`URL.createObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL). This download URL can then be assigned to an anchor element on which the user can click.

```js
fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL}/files/download/${props.id}`,
  {headers: {...}})
.then(function(response) {
  document.getElementById("anchor").download =
    response.headers.get("Content-Disposition").match(/filename="(.*)")/)[1];
  return response.blob();
})
.then(function(blob) {
  document.getElementById("anchor").href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
});
```

Comment: This helped my a lot! Thanks buddy. I have another question: This code downloads the file with a uuid name. Is there a way to download it with its original name?

Comment: Set the `<a download="...">` attribute to the filename, see my augmented answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Http Client` to send the token in header.

```
const handleDownload = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL}/files/download/${props.id}`, {
    headers: {
      token: '<your token>'
    }
  });
  const json = await res.json();
  console.log(json.data);
};
```

```
<a
  onClick={handleDownload}
  rel="noreferrer"
  target="_blank"
  download
  className="download-link"
  >
   Download File
</a>
```

I strongly suggest you convert `a` tag into a `button`.

Comment: I did what you suggested but now I'm getting "Unexpected token % in JSON at position 0" error. The backend is okay, as I'm getting a response whenever I click the handleDownload Button.

Comment: Are you getting this error from the backend or frontend?

Comment: As you can see on the backend, there I log the file when it succeeds. When I click the Download Button, the file logs in console so I guess it's a frontend problem. And yes I'm getting the error as a Modal as I'm handling the errors with Modals in React. Is there a chance that the error is due to using localStorage instead of Cookies?

Comment: I suggest you to send the base64 string from the backend and convert that base64 to a file and download it. It's an easier way.